# Improve performance of count and sum when already indexed

Tags: mysql, sql

First, here is the query I have:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as velocity_count, 
    SUM(`disbursements`.`amount`) as summation_amount 
FROM `disbursements` 
WHERE 
    `disbursements`.`accumulation_hash` = '40ad7f250cf23919bd8cc4619850a40444c5e90c978f88635a09ccf66a82ffb38e39ea51cdfd651b0ebdac5f5ca37cd7a17e0f60fea6cbce1397ccff5fa37346' 
    AND `disbursements`.`caller_id` = 1 
    AND `disbursements`.`active` = 1 
    AND (version_hash != '86b4111677294b27a1805643d193b8d437b6ddb170b4ed5dec39aa89bf070d160cbbcd697dfc1988efea8429b1f1557625bf956180c65d3dcd3a318280e0d2da') 
    AND (`disbursements`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2012-12-15 23:33:22' 
    AND '2013-01-14 23:33:22') LIMIT 1
```

Explain extended returns the following:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type  | possible_keys                                                                                                                                 | key                          | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | disbursements | range | unique_request_index,index_disbursements_on_caller_id,disbursement_summation_index,disbursement_velocity_index,disbursement_version_out_index | disbursement_summation_index | 1543    | NULL | 191422 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
```

The actual query counts about 95,000 rows.  If I explain another query that hits ~50 rows the explain is identical, just with fewer rows estimated.

The index being chosen covers accumulation_hash, caller_id, active, version_hash, created_at, amount in that order.

I've tried playing around with doing COUNT(id) or COUNT(caller_id) since these are non-null fields and return the same thing as count(*), but it doesn't have any impact on the plan or the run time of the actual query.

This is also a heavy insert table, essentially every single query will have had a row inserted or updated since the last time it was run, so the mysql query cache isn't entirely useful.

Before I go and make some sort of bucketed time sequence cache with something like memcache or redis, is there an obvious solution to getting this to work much faster?  A normal ~50 row query returns in 5MS, the ones across 90k+ rows are taking 500-900MS and I really can't afford anything much past 100MS.

I should point out the dates are a rolling 30 day window that needs to be essentially real time.  Expiration could probably happen with ~1 minute granularity, but new items need to be seen immediately upon commit.  I'm also on RDS, Read IOPS are essentially 0, and cpu is about 60-80%.  When I'm not querying the giant 90,000+ record items, CPU typically stays below 10%.

Comment: Just wondering, why the LIMIT 1 when you'll only get 1 anyway? Also, extra time is probably in the SUM not the COUNT - have you checked that?

Comment: Most likely a memory issues rather then a index issue.

Comment: Rails adds the Limit 1, it's obviously not needed, but it's getting injected so I left it to be thorough.  I've tried running the query as just the count, or just the sum, the run time seems to essentially be the same and the plan is also the same.

Comment: Can you tell if mysql is using a temp table on disk to perform this?

Comment: No temp is being used, according to this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html

Comment: How common is accumulation_hash? Maybe you could move that to an associated table, and then use accumulation_id to filter on a numeric value.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  But, accumulation_hash + date range is the majority of the selectivity here.  99.99% of the remaining records will not filter caller_id, active, or version_hash.

Comment: @WilliamThurston I was referring to the effort to compare strings. Even if they are indexed it's a heavy task. Can you move the value of accumulation_hash to another table, and then just look for the record ID (integer). Version_hash might need the same change. If a lot of disbursements records share the same accumulation_hash value, then this might give you some performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try an index that has `created_at` before `version_hash` (might get a better shot at having an index range scan... not clear how that non-equality predicate on the `version_hash` affects the plan, but I suspect it disables a range scan on the `created_at` column.

Other than that, the query and the index look about as good as you are going to get, the EXPLAIN output shows the query being satisfied from the index.

And the performance of the statement doesn't sound too unreasonable, given that it's aggregating 95,000+ rows, especially given the key length of 1543 bytes.  That's a much larger size than I normally deal with.

What are the datatypes of the columns in the index, and what is the cluster key or primary key?

```
accumulation_hash - 128-character representation of 512-bit value
caller_id - integer or numeric (?)
active - integer or numeric (?)
version_hash - another 128-characters
created_at - datetime (8bytes) or timestamp (4bytes)
amount - numeric or integer
```

95,000 rows at 1543 bytes each is on the order of 140MB of data.

Comment: It already says range for the type, so I assume I am getting that as is.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: @William: I was taking that to mean that it could be referring to just the leading columns in the index, BEFORE the non-equality predicate. (Perhaps the non-equality predicate is actually being handled as two range scans: one scan for values less than the "!= val", and another for values greater than the "!= val". It's certainly a range scan on all the columns before `version_hash`. If the date range doesn't eliminate rows, then it's not going to matter either way, it will need to check the same number of rows.

Comment: The primary key is an int(11) not shown in this query.  caller_id is also int(11), active is tinyint(1), created_at is a datetime, amount is an int(11), both hashes are varchar(255) in a utf-8 db/table/column.  I suppose I could take those down to the exact size of the actual hash, and remove the utf-8 encoding from those columns.  It'd probably still only reduce the key by half, or 2 thirds meaning I still have a query that's a bit too slow.  I'll make those changes for now and get started on caching I guess :)